# The distribution of a score test statistic in a special case

Tags: maximum-likelihood, chi-squared-test, lagrange-multipliers

Suppose that we want to test a restriction $\alpha=0$.

Unfortunately, we cannot directly estimate the parameter of interest $\alpha$.

Instead, we can calculate the log-likelihood functions with and without the restriction.

That is, we have $\mathcal{L}_r(\beta,\gamma)$ and $\mathcal{L}_u(\beta)$ (the restricted and unrestricted log-likelihood functions).

As the notation implies, we are facing a very special case: $\mathcal{L}_r$ contains one more parameter $\gamma$.

In this setup, if we implement the score (or lagrangian multiplier) test, we can use only the common parameter $\beta$.

That is, we have to derive the score function from $\mathcal{L}_u$, and then plug in the estimate $\hat{\beta}$ from $\mathcal{L}_{r}$ into the score.

Here, my question is that "does the score test statistic follow a chi-square distribution even in this special case?"